# Using auto layout disables scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xcode6, autolayout

I have a view that is too big to fit on the 3.5 inch so I made the view scrollable now however when I use auto layout to fit it to the iPhone 6 screen the view is no longer scrollable on the 3.5 inch screen. In the photo there are no constraints. But when I add constraints the view is no longer scrollable.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet var profileView: UIView!


    @IBAction func backToProfileViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }

    @IBOutlet var profilePictureView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var profileTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var usernameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func backToProfile(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }

    @IBAction func goToMailbox(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mailboxSegue", sender: self)

    }

    @IBAction func logOut(sender: AnyObject) {

        PFUser.logOut()

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedOutSegue", sender: self)

    }

    @IBAction func editProfile(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editSegue", sender: self)

    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.addSubview(profileView)
        //scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 550)


    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have constraints connected to all edges of your scroll view?

Comment: UIScrollView does not behave as other views with AutoLayout due to its specific nature. Please refer to this link for how to make AutoLayout work with UIScrollView. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: This link also could of good help. http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/